# How can krpano play videos inline on an iPhone?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone

The iPhone (until iOS8 at least) can't play videos inline. Every time the video starts, the video element goes fullscreen; if you exit the fullscreen the video pauses.

This has been the rule so far but I noticed that krpano can actually play an actual video **inline on iPhone** through WebGL: [demo](http://krpano.com/krpanocloud/video/airpano/index.html)

From what I can tell, they use a normal `<video>` element not attached to the document:

```js
var v = document.querySelector('video');

// remove from document
v.parentNode.removeChild(v); 

// touch anywhere to play
document.ontouchstart = function () {
  v.play();
}
```

```html
<video playsinline webkit-playsinline preload="auto" crossorigin="anonymous" src="http://www.mediactiv.com/video/Milano.mp4" loop style="transform: translateZ(0px);"></video>
Touch anywhere in here and wait for it to start.
```

But that alone doesn't seem to be enough: when the video is played, it goes fullscreen.

How do they manage to prevent the video from going fullscreen?

Comment: Also: you can use this to access the video element: `document.getElementById("krpanoSWFObject").get("plugin[video]").videoDOM`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, they skim the video inline and synchronize it to the audio, instead of actually `.play()`'ing it.

I wrote a module that takes care of playing the video and synchronizing it to the audio (but it also works on videos without a sound track): [iphone-inline-video](https://github.com/bfred-it/iphone-inline-video)